# Suma Algebraica de 2 Select SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql

Buenos Días, tengo los siguientes Select en SQL Server 2012, y necesito hacer una suma algebraica de ambos Select del los campos cantidad y total, ya que el resultado de cada uno me da valores positivos y negativos.

```
SELECT T0.U_CTS_Vendedor, T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T5.SLPNAME, T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo], SUM(T1.[Quantity]) AS CANTIDAD, SUM(T1.[LineTotal]) AS TOTAL FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode LEFT JOIN OSLP T5 ON T5.U_CTS_VENDEDORPOS = T0.U_CTS_Vendedor
WHERE ( T0.[DocDate] >= '[%1]' OR '[ %1]'=' ') and (T0.[DocDate] <= '[%2]' OR '[%2]'=' ') 
GROUP BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda], T5.SLPNAME,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]

UNION ALL

SELECT T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.[U_CTS_Cargo], T5.SLPNAME, T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo],SUM((T1.[Quantity]*(-1))) AS CANTIDAD, SUM((T1.[LineTotal]*(-1))) AS TOTAL FROM ORIN T0 INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode LEFT JOIN OSLP T5 ON T5.U_CTS_VENDEDORPOS = T0.U_CTS_Vendedor
WHERE ( T0.[DocDate] >= '[%1]' OR '[ %1]'=' ') and (T0.[DocDate] <= '[%2]' OR '[ %2]'=' ') 
GROUP BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda], T5.SLPNAME,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]
ORDER BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.SLPNAME,T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]
```

El resultado de estos Select es el siguiente:

```
T-010122    V20026844   T-01    5   PEDRO   ROPA    3   30.000
T-010122    V20026844   T-01    5   PEDRO   ROPA    -1  -10.000
```

Necesito que se vea así:

```
T-010122    V20026844   T-01    5   PEDRO   ROPA    2   20.000
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que no tengo mucha experiencia con SQL. :D

Answer (score 2):

lo que voy a hacer no se si es la mejor solucion, ya que no tengo mas datos respecto de tus tablas. Al parecer tus selects son de distintas tablas, con nombres muy raros, por lo que supongo sera algun sistema antiguo.

A tu select actual, envuelvelo en otro select.

```
SELECT 
U_CTS_Vendedor, 
U_CTS_Cedula,
U_CTS_Tienda,
U_CTS_Cargo,
SLPNAME,
U_bgn_grupoarticulo, 
SUM(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD, 
SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL
from
(

SELECT T0.U_CTS_Vendedor, T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T5.SLPNAME, T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo], SUM(T1.[Quantity]) AS CANTIDAD, SUM(T1.[LineTotal]) AS TOTAL FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode LEFT JOIN OSLP T5 ON T5.U_CTS_VENDEDORPOS = T0.U_CTS_Vendedor
WHERE ( T0.[DocDate] >= '[%1]' OR '[ %1]'=' ') and (T0.[DocDate] <= '[%2]' OR '[%2]'=' ') 
GROUP BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda], T5.SLPNAME,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]

UNION ALL
SELECT T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.[U_CTS_Cargo], T5.SLPNAME, T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo],SUM((T1.[Quantity]*(-1))) AS CANTIDAD, SUM((T1.[LineTotal]*(-1))) AS TOTAL FROM ORIN T0 INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode LEFT JOIN OSLP T5 ON T5.U_CTS_VENDEDORPOS = T0.U_CTS_Vendedor
WHERE ( T0.[DocDate] >= '[%1]' OR '[ %1]'=' ') and (T0.[DocDate] <= '[%2]' OR '[ %2]'=' ') 
GROUP BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda], T5.SLPNAME,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]
)
```

Fijate que tambien saque un order by, que en este caso sobra totalmente.

Tampoco entiendo los nombres entre llaves, ninguno de los campos tiene espacios en su nombre.

Comment: Ok, ya verifico...

El Query se genero desde el Generador de Reportes de SAP BS1.

Los Signos dentro de las llaves ('[%1]' ,'[%2]') son para que SAP en ese punto me pida valores de entrada (Desde , Hasta).

Ya me habían comentado lo de introducir mis Select en otro Select, pero no sabia bien como hacerlo, ya que como indique no soy experto en SQL.

Comment: tu base SAP esta en sql server?

Comment: Si, esta en SQL Server 2012.

Comment: No me funciono meter ambos Select en otro Select, no me reconoce los campos del Select Principal.

Comment: a que te refieres? que errores te devolvio? fijate de hacer un select * para ver que nombres de campo te devuelve y usar esos

Comment: Si hago el Select * me dice, Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ')' en la linea 12 que vendría siendo el ultimo paréntesis.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda, ya pude resolverlo... Me faltaba el alias del nuevo Select

```
SELECT 

SUMA.U_CTS_Vendedor AS CODIGO_VENDEDOR, 
SUMA.[U_CTS_Tienda] AS TIENDA, 
SUMA.SLPNAME AS VENDEDOR,
SUMA.[U_CTS_Cedula] AS CEDULA,
SUMA.[U_CTS_Cargo] AS CARGO,
SUMA.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo] AS RUBRO,
SUM(SUMA.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD, 
SUM(SUMA.TOTAL) AS TOTAL

FROM 

(

SELECT T0.U_CTS_Vendedor, T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T5.SLPNAME, T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo], SUM(T1.[Quantity]) AS CANTIDAD, SUM(T1.[LineTotal]) AS TOTAL FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode LEFT JOIN OSLP T5 ON T5.U_CTS_VENDEDORPOS = T0.U_CTS_Vendedor
WHERE ( T0.[DocDate] >= '2017-09-01' OR '2017-09-01'=' ') and (T0.[DocDate] <= '2017-09-01' OR '2017-09-01'=' ') 
GROUP BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda], T5.SLPNAME,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]

UNION ALL
SELECT T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T5.[U_CTS_Tienda],T5.[U_CTS_Cargo], T5.SLPNAME, T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo],SUM((T1.[Quantity]*(-1))) AS CANTIDAD, SUM((T1.[LineTotal]*(-1))) AS TOTAL FROM ORIN T0 INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode LEFT JOIN OSLP T5 ON T5.U_CTS_VENDEDORPOS = T0.U_CTS_Vendedor
WHERE ( T0.[DocDate] >= '2017-09-01' OR '2017-09-01'=' ') and (T0.[DocDate] <= '2017-09-01' OR '2017-09-01'=' ') 
GROUP BY T5.[U_CTS_Tienda], T5.SLPNAME,T5.[U_CTS_Cedula],T0.U_CTS_Vendedor,T5.[U_CTS_Cargo],T1.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]

) AS SUMA

GROUP BY SUMA.[U_CTS_Tienda], SUMA.SLPNAME,SUMA.[U_CTS_Cedula],SUMA.U_CTS_Vendedor,SUMA.[U_CTS_Cargo],SUMA.[U_bgn_grupoarticulo]
```